# Rect not being drawn on Android PdfDocument canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, android-canvas

I just switched from using iText to the native android `PdfDocument`, due to lack of documentation of [how to print iText documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337355/how-do-you-print-a-pdf-generated-by-itext-using-a-custom-printdocumentadapter-im).

I am trying to draw a table on the `Canvas`, by looping through a list and adding a right and left column for each item, represented by using the `Rect`

The function responsible for  drawing the table rows is shown below:

```kotlin
fun drawTableRow(canvas: Canvas, question: Document.H) {
            val textBounds = Rect()

            var cellHeight = if(question.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                20f
            } else {
                paint.getTextBounds(question.value, 0, question.value!!.length, textBounds)
                textBounds.height().toFloat()
            }
            if(cellHeight <= 20f) cellHeight = 20f

            paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT

            val top = yPointer
            val right = (width.toFloat() - (pageMargin * 2)) / 3
            val bottom = height - (yPointer + cellHeight + pageMargin)

            val leftCell = RectF(pageMargin, top, right, bottom)
            val rightCell = RectF(leftCell.right, top, pageMargin, bottom)

            var textY = yPointer + yPadding

            canvas.drawRect(rightCell, contentBgPaint)
            canvas.drawRect(leftCell, contentBgPaint)

            canvas.drawText(question.h.hQuestion.title, 0, question.h.hQuestion.title.length, pageMargin, textY, paint)
            canvas.drawText(question.h.hQuestion.subtitle, 0, question.h.hQuestion.subtitle.length, pageMargin, textY + 16f, paint)
            canvas.drawText(question.value!!, 0, question.value!!.length, leftCell.right, textY, paint)

            yPointer += cellHeight.toInt()
        }
```

And when running the debugger, the `Rect` coordinates seem to be set correctly.

[image: Debugger]

However, an usual behavior occurs - either only one rectangle is being drawn, or the rectangles are overlapping each other exactly, despite having different coordinates.

Because if I attempt to only draw the right rectangle, it still appears on the left side in the document, with the exact proportions of the left rectangle, as seen in the image below.

[image: Pdf screenshot]

Comment: This channel has uploaded a lot of videos regarding iText. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YlxFuCPQqc&list=PLFh8wpMiEi89IAlJLfw43YjO0DRqhOpaF

Comment: @KamalNayan I am not using iText anymore, and I am aware of his content. Unfortunately he does not have anything related to printing, which made me change from iText to the native implementation in the first place.

Comment: tried this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3tWuwEA-Jw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake. [The documentation for RectF](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/RectF) clearly states that left <= right and top <= bottom. The debugger clearly shows that the right cell has a left value that is > right.

I replaced `pageMargin` with `width.toFloat() - pageMargin` in the right cell, which solved the issue.